# Are the basic arithmetic operations not available in relational algebra?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Can we use the basic '+', '-', '*', '/' operations in relational algebra? For example, if I want to know the difference of John's and Smith's salaries from an EMPLOYEE relation, I could write

```
select e1.salary - e2.salary
from employee as e1, employee as e2
where e1.name = 'John' and e2.name = 'Smith';
```

How to represent this statement in relational algebra?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so, because, as it is said, relational algebra gives only a way to express things thanks to relation, not calculation.

I was wondering if it were working for relational calculus, but I'm not even sure your query should have a translation...:

```
{t.salary|Employee(t)^(∃ e1 Employee(e1))
                     ^(∃ e2 Employee(e2))
                     ^(e1=John)
                     ^(e2=Smith)
                     ^???}
```

Nonetheless, relational algebra and relational calculus are the basis of the SQL language, so, if you can do such a calculation in SQL, I'm wondering why isn't there at least one way to do it in one of these two basis...